# Proper error handling when connecting to Mailchimp api

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, promise, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Relatively new to Node. I'm building a rudimentary app that signs up users to an e-mail newsletter, by consuming [MailChimp's API](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/). To subscribe users on my Mailchimp account, I have the following POST route which [uses their Node library](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-node/).

```
/*** POST route endpoint ***/
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serving a POST request at root route.");

  // Define data member based on parameters of req
  // and global constants.
  const member = {
      email_address: req.body.email,
      email_type: EMAIL_TYPE,
      status: SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS,
      language: LANGUAGE,
      vip: VIP,
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: req.body.firstName,
        LNAME: req.body.lastName
      }
  };

  mailchimpClient.setConfig({
    apiKey: MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
    server: SERVER,
  });

  // Define async function that makes a call to the mailchimp batch POST lists/{list_id} endpoint.
  const postIt = async () => {
    const response = await mailchimpClient.lists.batchListMembers(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, {
      members: [member],
      update_existing: false
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));  // Want to read some output in terminal
  };

  // Call the async function you defined
  postIt()
      .then(()=>res.send("<h1>All good, thanks!</h1>"))
      .catch(()=>res.send("<h1>Error!</h1>"));
});
```

To test if the code responds correctly to errors, I add the following fictional user twice:

[image: Jane Doe inserted in our subscriber database twice.]

The first time, everything succeeds as expected on both server and terminal. Server:

[image: Jane Doe is stored on our server.]

and terminal output:

[image: The first POST succeeds without issue.]

while the user themselves are presented with the `<h1>` that reads "All good, thanks!":

[image: All good message.]

But the second time I put in Jane Doe's information, while Mailchimp clearly does give me the expected error (since `update_existing` is `false` in definition of `postIt()`), my failure callback in `catch()` is **not** called, and the user is still served with a success message in their browser!

[image: Second POST fails according to Mailchimp]

So what we have here is a POST call designed to fail, but it seems that I am probably not using the `Promise` returned by `postIt()` very well. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like the mailchimp client throws an exception to catch.

Notice how your 2nd console log executes even when the mailchimp client is "failing", so there's nothing to catch. It appears to just populate a "errors" key in the response. Many APIs do this in their own way.. some have a "status" field etc.

If you want to catch this error in your promise catch handler, you'll have to detect the failure scenario in your async function by parsing that mailchimp response and throwing an exception yourself.

```
 const postIt = async () => {
    const response = await mailchimpClient.lists.batchListMembers(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, {
      members: [member],
      update_existing: false
    });
    if (response.errors.length) { 
         throw new Error(response.errors);
    }
  };
  postIt().catch(errors => console.log(errors));
```

Comment: Ah yes, a few minutes after posting this I thought to myself that that exact line, the `console.log()`, makes it so that `postIt()` actually never throws anything bad. The mailchimp call never throws anything, so it's all good. I sometimes find it hard to understand whether an API call throws if it has an error or populates the JSON payload and I have to figure it out. Thank you for this response, which I am accepting.